# Drawing using canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, android-canvas, android-studio

Hi Im new to Android Development and I wish to get my head around drawing with canvas.
I have several questions which the develop.android.com website doesn't make clear:

-Can you use a simple canvas for different views or do you have to create a new canvas each time you wish to add a new view?

-Are bitmaps the only image type "things" that can be drawn onto a canvas? for example in my code below I have a drawable called swirls however I cannot use this, do I have to convert it to a bitmap? And how do I do that?

package ple.kon15;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DrawBG extends View {
Bitmap swirls = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.swirls);
public DrawBG(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(swirls, swirls.getWidth(), swirls.getHeight(),null);
}
    public DrawBG(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
    public DrawBG(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, each View has its own Canvas.
2. You can convert drawable resources to Bitmaps using:
   `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_resource);`

Answer (score 0):

1- yes, every view has its own canvas but you can also have complex views that has one canvas,
2- you should decode it with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(your_context.getResources(), R.drawable.swirls);` to use. And no not only bitmap, you can draw lines, vertex, rectangles, rounded rectangles, paths with canvas, and if you want to do more complex things like a game or a complex animation, you can also use `SurfaceView` but you should think really carefully since it's a bit more advanced and give all the handling of surcace to you